# Databinding not incremental on AGP 4.0.1

Tags: android, android-databinding, annotation-processing, incremental-build

I'm currently using Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.1 and it seems like Databinding is not incremental on AGP 4.0.1, as you can see on the below image:

[image]

`android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding`

I've checked the dependencies of the project and I don't import the databinding dependency directly. I enable it like this:

```
android {
   ...
   buildFeatures {
     dataBinding = true
   }
}
```

Is there anything else I should do so databinding can be incremental?

Comment: where dataBinding compiler dependencies?

Comment: @chandmohd I'm sorry, but I didn't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

To use dataBinding to your project do following:

```
android {
   ...
   buildFeatures {
     dataBinding = true
   }
}

dependencies {
    def databinding = "3.5.1"
    implementation "com.android.databinding:compiler:$databinding"
     ..... 
     }
```

Then bind your layout with `<layout>....</layout>` tag at root level

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/parentCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_medium"
        app:contentPadding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_large"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        app:elevation="4dp"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: The `implementation` part isn't on the docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start#build_environment

Comment: U can use ``kapt`` instead if your are using kotlin this will generate Class for each XML

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin & Kapt, as per Kotlin Gradle Documentation:

> Note that the first build isn't incremental in any case.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#incremental-compilation

Check second or later build does not show the warning.

Also check all annotation process you are using is incremental:

> Currently, annotation processing can be incremental only if all
> annotation processors being used are incremental.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#incremental-annotation-processing-since-1330

Also check for Build Logs, you might see error like this:

> Task :app:kaptDevDebugKotlin 
> 1.8.0_101-b13 has a bug (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8007720) that prevents Room
> from being incremental.
> Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC)

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem when I was running unit tests,
the problem was with the dagger and the following dependencies,
I removed the test dependencies and the problem solved

```
kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${daggerVersion}"
kaptTest "com.squareup.inject:assisted-inject-processor-dagger2:${assistedInjectVersion}"
```